# Delegate and Callback not working for passing Model data

Tags: ios, swift, callback, delegates

I am trying to pass data from a firstVC to a second VC I have tried using delegate but it never worked (did not show required response) so I tried callback too and it now working so I am pasting both lines of code so any help is welcomed

Delegate:

```
protocol RatingDelegate: class {
    func didLoadRating(ratings : [RatingModel])
}
```

the viewcontroller which the data would be passed from

ViewController A:

```
var delegate : RatingDelegate?
func showRatings(ratings: [RatingModel]) {

        if delegate != nil {
            delegate?.didLoadRating(ratings: ratings)
        }
    }
```

where the delegate value is supposed to me printed

RatingVC:

```
extension RatingVC: RatingDelegate {
    func didLoadRating(ratings: [RatingModel]) {
        log(ratings)
    }

}
```

**The callback Version**

The view controller that would get the data

```
var ratingsCallBack: (() -> ([RatingModel]))?
```

the view controller which the value would be passed from

```
func showRatings(ratings: [RatingModel]) {

        let ratingVC = RatingVC()
        ratingVC.ratingsCallBack!() = {[unowned self] in
            return ratings
        }
    }
```

this how ever throws a response saying

> Expression is not assignable: function call returns immutable value

Comment: "I have tried using delegate but it never worked (did not show required response)": Did you at least passed the `delegate != nil` test? Was it set?

Comment: You never assign a value to the `delegate` property.

Comment: FYI - the `if delegate != nil` check is unnecessary.

Comment: @rmaddy how do I do that?

Comment: removed it already

Comment: Show this code in context. What class has the `delegate` property and the `showRatings` method? And where do you create an instance of that class? Update your question with these details.

Comment: @rmaddy @Larme it is more complex beacuse I am passing data to a `Viewcontroller B`.  I am not sending data to `viewcontroller A`

Comment: @rmaddy the delegate is in a different file, I am passing the data from ViewController A to  RatingVC updated the question

Comment: To fix the error remove the parentheses (and the exclamation mark) `ratingVC.ratingsCallBack = { ... }` and `RatingVC()` is most likely not the instance you expect.

Comment: You seem confused by passing data forward vs backward and delegate vs injection. Do you know when to use one over the other and how they differ?

Comment: no I dont know yet

Comment: If I were you, I would definitely spend today learning that. Passing objects forward (VCA to VCB), backward (VCB to VCA), and all around (VCX to VCH) is at the heart of everything you are doing. There are lots of good articles (including Swift documentation) about when to use dependency injection and when to use delegates (optionally with protocols).

Comment: @bsod did that and figured out the issue thanks

Answer (score 1):

So the FirstVC passes data to RatingVC.

On FirstVC, at the point were you invoke RatingVC you should assign the delegate.

```
let ratingVC = RatingVC()
self.delegate = ratingVC //Here you specify RatingVC is the delegate variable

self.present(ratingVC, animated: true)
```

also

```
if delegate != nil {

}
```

is unnecessary, just do `delegate?.didLoadRating(ratings: ratings)` to keep it cleaner

---

EDIT: For the callback version is the same, just assign the value to the callback before initializing the view controller that sends the data.

Comment: `RatingVC` is the one with VC I am send data to, I am not passing data from it

Comment: I know. Is RatingVC the one that opens the second VC?

Comment: No, the second VC  opens the RatingVC

Comment: so RatingVC is the second VC in this case

Comment: Ok lets call the first one DataOriginVC and RatingVC (is the destination and second VC). Then when you open RatingVC you should assign the delegate. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks strange:

```
var ratingsCallBack: (() -> ([RatingModel]))?
```

should be something like this:

```
var ratingsCallBack: (([RatingModel]) -> ())?
```

so in case with callback:

```
class A: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let ratingVC = RatingVC()
        ratingVC.ratingsCallBack = { arr in
            arr.forEach({ (model) in
                print(model.rating)
            })
        }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(ratingVC, animated: false)
    }
}

class RatingVC: UIViewController {

    var ratingsCallBack: (([RatingModel]) -> ())?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    @IBAction private func someButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let arr = [RatingModel.init(rating: 5), RatingModel()]
        ratingsCallBack?(arr)
    }
}

struct RatingModel {
    var rating: Int = 1
}
```

Then when you press "someButton" you get this array in controller "A"